# Etherscan says there is not enough ether, why?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, error

Etherscan says there is not enough ether, why? Arguments, which i enter => requestLoan(3,31,3) and after change account, provideGuarantee(0,3)

I have created dApp and how it looks in my code you can see here

```
this.etherAmount = 3;
await this.bankContract.methods.requestLoan(this.etherAmount, 31, 2).send({from: this.state.borrower}).then(res => console.log("Request loan " + res.status));
await this.bankContract.methods.provideGuarantee(0, 4).send({from: this.state.guarantor, gas: 40000, value: this.etherAmount}).then(res => console.log("Provide guarantee " + res.status));
```

Link to transaction => https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xab31946f54cb86187dd517ff7c8ebc34730714a9717ee33a11ea22d54a31ed11

```
function requestLoan(uint etherBorrow, uint8 payBackDate, uint8 
etherInterest) public
{
    Loan memory loan = Loan({loanee: msg.sender, index: loansCount, etherBorrow: etherBorrow,
                                    payBackDate: now + (payBackDate * 1 days), etherInterest: etherInterest,
                                    _isGuaranteeProvided: false, _isLoanProvided: false, _isLoanExist: true});
    loans[loansCount] = loan;
    loansCount++;
}

function provideGuarantee(uint index, uint8 guaranteeInterest) public payable // payable means that value should have ether
{
    require(
        index < loansCount,
        "This index does not exist");

    require(loans[index].loanee != msg.sender,
            "The borrower can't provide a guarantee to himself");

    require(lenders[index] != msg.sender,
            "The lender can't provide guarantee for the loan");

    require(!loans[index]._isGuaranteeProvided, 
        "This loan already has a guarantee");

    require(guaranteesCount < loansCount || !guarantees[index]._isWaitingForHandling, 
        "This guarantee already waiting for handling of borrower");

    require(guaranteeInterest > 0, 
            "Too low interest");

    require(
        msg.value == loans[index].etherBorrow,
        "You don't have enough eather to provide guarantee");

    require(
        loans[index]._isLoanExist,
        "This loan does not exist");

    require(
        !guarantees[index]._isGuaranteeExist,
        "This guarantee does exist");

    Guarantee memory guarantee = Guarantee({guarantor: msg.sender, etherInterest: guaranteeInterest,
                                                loanIndex: index, _isWaitingForHandling: true, _isGuaranteeExist: true});
    guarantees[index] = guarantee;
    guaranteesCount++;
}
```

Comment: It's impossible to read your code given the combination of horizontal scroll and vertical scroll required in order to view it.

Answer (score 1):

You are providing 3 `wei` as `value` to your `provideGuarantee` function - the same amount you are creating a loan for. In your code you check that if the amount is the same (`msg.value == loans[index].etherBorrow`) then the contract throws that error: `Fail with error 'You don&#39;t have enough eather to provide guarantee`.

I'm a bit unsure why you have such a condition and what exactly you are trying to do but probably you simply need to provide more Ethers (weis) as the `value`?

Answer (score 0):

As stated by LauriPeltonen the check that fails is `msg.value == loans[index].etherBorrow` since you send 3wei then `loans[index].etherBorrow` is not 3 when index = 0.

Looking at the transaction history the first successful call to `requestLoan` was at `https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x879a238d031e81bac5cc2092a8897b6feaa8f269c0be737ad313c812e4aaef22`. Withe the following parameters.

- etherBorrow = 300000000000
- payBackDate = 31
- etherInterest = 5

So unless you have some other function to override a loan data calling to `provideGuarantee(0, 4)` will fail unless you send 300000000000 wei = 300 gwei.

I'd suggest to always generate events when creating a load so looking at the events you can determine things like index that are assigned during execution.